# Array List Calculator

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

My plan is to create an app with 1 editText where a user enters any number and 5-6 fields of ArrayList where this entered number will be multiplied by 2, 3 and etc.

The problem is that my app crashes after launching, need some help :/

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText numberEntered = findViewById(R.id.enterNum);

    int enteredNum = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(numberEntered));
    

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView listView1 = findViewById(R.id.listNum);

        ArrayList<Integer> intArray = new ArrayList<>();

        ArrayAdapter <Integer> intAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, intArray);

        listView1.setAdapter(intAdapter);

        listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                intArray.add(2 * enteredNum);
                intArray.add(3 * enteredNum);
                intArray.add(4 * enteredNum);
                intArray.add(5 * enteredNum);
            }
        });
```

Comment: what is the error log ?

Comment: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.timetable/com.example.timetable.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0):

Try moving these lines into your onCreate method after `setContent`

```
 EditText numberEntered = findViewById(R.id.enterNum);

 int enteredNum = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(numberEntered));
```

and put `Integer.parseInt` into a `try/catch block` else it will throw an exception when the EditText is empty.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        EditText numberEntered = findViewById(R.id.enterNum);
    
        int enteredNum = -1;
        
        try{
           enteredNum = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(numberEntered));
         } catch(Exception exception){
           //do something with error
         }

        ListView listView1 = findViewById(R.id.listNum);

        ArrayList<Integer> intArray = new ArrayList<>();

        ArrayAdapter <Integer> intAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, intArray);

        listView1.setAdapter(intAdapter);

        listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                intArray.add(2 * enteredNum);
                intArray.add(3 * enteredNum);
                intArray.add(4 * enteredNum);
                intArray.add(5 * enteredNum);
            }
        });
}
```